# OpenGL- Flat Shading without light C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I have already implemented a mesh. It was OK with a wire frame rendering (triangles) but now i want to apply a flat shading rendering and what i get is a figure with no volume, plain white.

here is what i use:

```
for(int i=0; i<mesh->nt; i++) {
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);


    int i0 = mesh->triangles[i].vInds[0];
    int i1 = mesh->triangles[i].vInds[1];
    int i2 = mesh->triangles[i].vInds[2];

    Vector n1 = GetNormal(mesh->vertices[i0], mesh->vertices[i1], mesh-                  >vertices[i2]);

    glNormal3dv((double *)&n1);

    glVertex3dv((double *)&mesh->vertices[i0]);
    glVertex3dv((double *)&mesh->vertices[i1]);
    glVertex3dv((double *)&mesh->vertices[i2]);

    glEnd();
}
```

I calculated the normals of the triangles but nothing works.  Any idea?

Comment: As a side note, I would suggest reading something like http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ if you want to learn modern OpenGL programming. The functions you are using are deprecated!

Answer (score 6):

If you didn't enable lights/lighting, the triangles won't be shaded. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

maybe that is better?

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); // <-- start triangles before the loop, much faster

for(int i=0; i<mesh->nt; i++) 
{
    int i0 = mesh->triangles[i].vInds[0];
    int i1 = mesh->triangles[i].vInds[1];
    int i2 = mesh->triangles[i].vInds[2];

    Vector n1 = GetNormal(mesh->vertices[i0], 
                          mesh->vertices[i1], 
                          mesh->vertices[i2]);

    glNormal3dv((double *)&n1);

    glVertex3dv((double *)&mesh->vertices[i0]);
    glVertex3dv((double *)&mesh->vertices[i1]);
    glVertex3dv((double *)&mesh->vertices[i2]);
}   
glEnd();
```